# jquery change selected radio button on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the checkout the customer can either choose to pay a set deposit, the full amount or a value between the set deposit and full amount.

The radio button is selected on the set deposit as default, if they decide to pay a specific amount the corresponding radio button is selected instead.

Its harder to explain than it is so show.

```
    <div class="grey_header" style="margin:20px 10px 0px 10px; width:80%; padding:10px; background-color:#efefef; text-align:center"><strong>Order Payment Options</strong></div>
    <div style="margin:0px 10px; padding:10px; width:80%">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="50" height="70" align="center"><label>
            <input name="pay_amount" type="radio" id="radio" value="deposit" checked="checked" />
          </label></td>
          <td><font class="grey_header">Pay initial deposit</font><br />
            This option will pay the initial deposit required before we can process this order.</td>
          <td align="center"><b><font class="current_price">&pound;345.00</font></b>
            <input type=hidden name="order_deposit" value="345"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50" height="70" align="center"><label>
            <input name="pay_amount" type="radio" id="radio" value="full" />
          </label></td>
          <td><font class="grey_header">Pay full balance</font><br />
            This option will pay off the full balance of this order.</td>
          <td width="150" align="center"><b><font class="current_price">&pound;1,724.00</font></b><br />

            <input type=hidden name="order_deposit" value="1724"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50" height="70" align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="pay_amount" id="pay_other" value="other" />
          </label></td>
                        <td><font class="grey_header">Pay different amount</font><br />
            This option will allow you to pay a specific amount between &pound;346.00 and &pound;1,724.00.</td>
          <td align="center"><b><font class="current_price">&pound;
            <input name="order_deposit" type="text" class="current_price" id="order_deposit" value="862.00" autocomplete="off" size="6" />
          </font></b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Ive created a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ashpb/hfLn2jcs/

If the customer clicks on the input field with 862.00 in it, the bottom radio button is selected instead of the default top one.

Comment: Are you saying that if someone clicks on the 862 text field that you want the "Pay different amount" radio button selected? What JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: I think the problem is there doesn't seem to be any JavaScript at all...

Comment: ive tried various bits of code from all over the internet and nothing seems to be working, hence why i haven't included any javascript in the jsfiddle, didnt want to confuse things :(

Comment: @j08691 yes that exactly what im trying to achieve, just cant seem to get anything to work, not good with jquery at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add jquery script, to change the radio button on input change.
use .focus() or .focusin() method for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#order_deposit').focusin(function(){
         $('#pay_other').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

and if user left it blank and leave the input box, then you can reset the default radio button like this:

```
 $('#order_deposit').focusout(function(){
       if($('#order_deposit').val()==''){            
            $('#radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
         }
    });
```

Comment: i been trying this all day but it doesnt seem to select the radio button when the input box is click or value is changed, im using jquery version 1.7.2, could that be the problem?

Comment: i think you can try with .focusin() function, it is included in jquery 1.4, hope that helps you, well i am trying to provide you alternative to this also.

Comment: thanks, ive put this code you have provided into the fiddle but its not working :(

Comment: can you check console for any error for this part of code...

Comment: i am trying at my end, at my system.

Comment: it is working perfectly at my end now, i have edited some code above, try it now.

Comment: thank-you so much for your help  - working great

Comment: welcome. hope you got your solution. cheers.

Comment: actually you need to provide a different id to all your radio button controls as 2 of them have the same id, this will affect the jquery call.

Comment: yes i noticed this and have updated the fiddle :)